# How do I boot into single-user mode from GRUB?

Tags: boot, grub2

After changing a few lines in xorg.conf, I can no longer boot Ubuntu (I assume it breaks when trying to load up X), so I need a way to boot into a single-user mode. However, there seems to be zero guides on the Internet how to do it, because they all assume I can actually edit files on my computer, and I obviously can't.

So how do I load Ubuntu in single-user mode?

When I turned off splash, I figured out the problem: whenever Ubuntu can't load X server due to some error, it switches to tty1 and waits for the prompt, but doesn't turn off the splash.

Comment: Could you provide a little more info about your update? Why does not turning off `splash` when Ubuntu can't load X server lead to problems?

Comment: @irrationalJohn Because splash screen doesn't disappear so you can't see the console and might not even realize it's there ready for the login.

Comment: Pressing `ESC` will toggle the screen between diag and splash during boot. That way you can see whatever messages are displayed. Everything is logged in /var/log/dmesg if you end up unable to boot and mount the drive on another system.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

To boot into `single user` mode you edit the boot instructions for the GRUB menu entry you wish to boot and add the kernel parameter/option `single`. Brief instructions for how to do this are below.

1. Hold down the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while rebooting to bring up GRUB menu
2. Select (highlight) the GRUB boot menu entry you wish to use.
3. Press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the GRUB boot commands for the selected boot menu entry.
4. Look near the bottom of the list of commands for lines similar to

   ```
   linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic root=UUID=bc6f8146-1523-46a6-8b\
   6a-64b819ccf2b7 ro  quiet splash
   initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic
   ```
5. Change the middle line in (4) by adding the kernel boot parameter `single` to the end of the line (i.e. after `ro  quiet splash`).

   For this example you would change:

   ```
   6a-64b819ccf2b7 ro  quiet splash
   ```

   to

   ```
   6a-64b819ccf2b7 ro  quiet splash single
   ```
6. Press either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot using
   these kernel options.

**Note:** These changes are **not** persistent. Any change to the kernel boot options made this way will only affect the next boot and only if you start that boot by pressing either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> while still in GRUB edit mode.

Comment: how about changing `ro` to `rw` so the file system gets mounted writable, so you can make your changes stick?

Comment: Left shift doesnt do a thing. Is there a new way to do this?

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04, at least, its "ESC" now, to get into the GRUB menu.

Comment: You can abbreviate the `single` to just `S` if you find yourself rebooting often.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Ubuntu 20, but these's another [this one did](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/reset-your-forgotten-ubuntu-password-in-2-minutes-or-less/): the **Alternate Root Shell Method**

Comment: I had to repeatedly press the left shift key, holding it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 57):

Occasionally, you might not be able to use the `single` method as described in the accepted answer. In those cases you can tell the Linux kernel to use a different init like so:

```
init=/bin/bash
```

#### For example

[image: ss]

Comment: This method is useful for recovering from lost system password as it gives you a shell without being prompted for the existing password.

Comment: This is not working anymore on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: This did work for me on Ubuntu 20.04. Note that the underlined part is `rw init=/bin/bash`, **NOT** `rw \init=/bin/bash` (the backslash is only an escape in the rendeder to let you know the line continues below)

Answer (score 14):

Good question! When booting the machine hold down the left shift key. For more info follow this:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Comment: Recovery mode refuses to load just like the usual mode.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why the instruction is not permanent.

To make it permanent edit "/etc/default/grub"

```
pico /etc/default/grub
```

Make the same changes...

```
update-grub
```

I changed the line "ro quiet splash "

to "ro text single " and i start GUI with

```
startx
```

Comment: It's not supposed to be permanent, it's damage control.

Answer (score 2):

[slm](https://askubuntu.com/users/17531/slm)'s [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/760064/560458) worked for me in `Ubuntu 20.04` when I had changed the ownership of the entire `/etc` directory.

I followed [the instructions here](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/reset-your-forgotten-ubuntu-password-in-2-minutes-or-less/) (in the **Alternate Root Shell Method** section) and by the grace of Jesus I could **boot in SINGLE USER MODE**. Then I could get into the **root shell** **without the root password** (which Ubuntu doesn't give you).

This is done (roughly) as follows:

0. reboot
1. enter the GRUB console by pressing `shift` (left, right, or both?) during the **boot splash**
2. select the regular kernel image you always boot from (this wasn't in the top-level menu, but in a menu 1 level deep)
3. press `e`
4. go to the line that starts with `linux` and move the cursor to the end
5. remove the part that says `ro quiet splash` (or something like that) and add this at the end of the line: `rw init=/bin/bash`
6. press Ctrl-x to boot into that image with these boot parameters

That's roughly what allowed me to get into a root shell **without** the root password.

Don't let Ubuntu lock you out of your own computer with their *"recommended measures"* (ie. forcing you to use `sudo`, or not giving you the **root user** of your own computer). (Maybe there's a good reason for those, I don't know.)