# passwd problem Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, passwd

I'm running Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS and since the latest update of the `passwd` program I can't logon to the System anymore. If I enter a vaild user password the system shows me the login dialog again or closes the connection if I try to logon using ssh. If I enter a wrong password the system reacts as usual. The only way to get access to a shell is to boot into the recovery mode.

Moreover if I enter `passwd` or `passwd <Username>` in the recorvery mode root shell the passwd application simply closes itself.

What can I do to solve this problem? I thought about compiling the program and trying the self-compiled version.

Comment: You say "Ubuntu Server", then you say "login dialog": are you talking about the graphical login or on the command line?

Comment: I'm logging in via command line.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried booting into single user mode and try using passwd in there?
Let me know if need a guide on how to boot into single user mode.

Keep in mind to change the password for a user you need to type it in after the command.
Ex: passwd userName

Comment: That is no answer.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I booted into single user mode using [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub) tutorial and I'm still having the problem. Moreover I switched into single user mode from the recovery system using the command `init 1`. `who -r` shows me that I'm in runlevel S, which is equal to runlevel one. However, the problem still appears.