# Users not created during installation

Tags: users

I've successfully installed Ubuntu 12.04. On re-booting I was presented with the logon screen and on entering the password for the user, I get an invalid password error.

On searching for a solution, I stumbled upon http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword. However, after going down to the 'root' on entering "ls /home" I see no users.

I can logon using the 'Guest' session and from within that session, I can see a user account.

How do I logon with the created user account ? How do I reset the password for that account ?

Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: I believe that the invalid password error was because your password was too short or was a sequence of numbers (like `123456789123456789`). If you have access to the root user you should create a new user using `adduser username` changing the username for the name of the user you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Your installation was not successful as the user that you created in the install was not created, Can you not just try the install again? Else you can:

1) Boot in [single user mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub)

2) Add new user

`sudo useradd -m -G adm,cdrom,sudo,dip,plugdev yourusername`

`passwd yourusername`

3) Reboot and login.

Comment: As I could see the user created during installation from within the 'Guest' session, I had a hunch that '/home' was not mounted. So, in recovery mode, I mounted all with command "mount --all" I could then see the user I created with command 'ls /home', changed the password of that user and continued the boot procedure. However, when I gave the new password for the user on the logon screen, the screen blinked for a second and reverted to the logon screen without it actually logging into /home. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Can you login to a tty? 'Ctrl + alt +f2'

Comment: How did you change your uses password?

Comment: After first finding the users using 'ls /home', I changed the password of the user in question with 'passwd username' command.

Comment: I created a new user with the 'Guest' account by going into the user account settings and unlocking the main user with the new password. I am now able to logon using this new user created. However, I would prefer to logon using the original user, as this user has administrative privileges. Also, how do I get '/home' to mount rather than go through this process of going through the 'recovery' mode ?

Comment: I don't know how you could of changed another users password from the guest account, your install sounds really messed up, why cannot you reinstall?

Comment: Is there a set procedure to re-install (ie) uninstall in a particular sequence and then re-install ?

Comment: No unless you had data you wanted to keep, just boot the install media again and run through the setup again.