# How can I boot to linux command line from GRUB?

Tags: grub2, gnome, debian

I botched a gnome install on my virtual box and now when it boots it just hangs up at a black screen.  I wante to get back into a command line and uninstall/reinstall gnome...

Comment: After all fails you can still [boot into a root shell](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell).

Comment: I don't even know what the hell happened but somehow my box ended up booting to a command line after rebooting several times...so I din't even really get a chance to try any of your answers...

Answer (score 5):

Edit the entry from the Grub screen when it comes up (press `e`)

Find the kernel line and add either `single` or `init=/bin/sh` to the end of it then press `Ctrl`+`X` to boot.

Alternatively have you tried pressing `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1` to get to a terminal?

See also https://askubuntu.com/a/132983/354175

Comment: You might also try mashing Esc while the computer is booting.  see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Answer (score 5):

ya, if grub doesn't show a menu, hold [shift] when it's starting.  Go to your Ubuntu version's menu item, and press 'e' to edit.  Go down to the linux start line, which contains 'vmlinuz' followed by a bunch of other fun stuff.  Insert 'text' before the part '$vt_handoff'.  Removing 'splash' and 'quiet' will let you see what's going on.  You should try that while trying to boot into desktop graphics as well!