# Bought used Ubuntu laptop, can't change password to access account

Tags: login, password, reset

I recently purchased a used ubuntu 14.04 laptop. The previous owner didn't scrub their account and I want to reset the computer to set up my own account. I can't do this feature from the guest session, so I'm trying to reset the account password.

I followed the tutorial [here](http://psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword) and [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/11/reset-user-password-ubuntu-14-04/) (they're pretty much the same thing). Whenever I continue with normal resume, I enter my new password but it keeps returning to the login screen.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is there a better way to reset the account and set up my own? What are my options?

Comment: You could simply install Ubuntu over, just a thought.

Comment: @xangua That would imply having to re-install a multitude of applications all over again, something I'd like to avoid

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a Login Loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Could either...

- boot into [single user mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub) (use boot / grub option `single`) or
- boot into [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) (hold shift while booting, choose "root sell" - same as single user mode?)

Then change that user's password (as root) with `passwd user`

### Or use [live recovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery)

1. Boot a live iso / cd / dvd / usb
2. mount your `/` partition (to `/mnt` for example)
3. `sudo chroot /mnt`
4. `passwd user`