# How to start a KVM-guest as single user mode

Tags: boot, grub2, kvm-virtualization, single-user

How to start a KVM-guest as single user mode?

When I tried to start the VM as sigle user mode, it displayed "Booting a command line" on the screen and got stucked. This guest VM starts fine as multi user mode.

Here is the procedure I did:

1. Start a guest VM on a Host.

   ```
   $ virsh start --console myguestvm
   ```
2. Select a menu on grub menu and press <kbd>e</kbd>.
3. Edit a line below and add "single" parameter

   ```
   linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-20-generic root=UUID=XXXXX ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
   ```
4. Then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the link for reference :http://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the $vt_handoff, quiet, and splash parts of the line.

The vt_handoff option causes the kernel not to display the text console so that there can be a flickerless transition to Xwindows when it starts up, which is why you don't see anything when you boot to single user mode.  The splash option tells `plymouth` to show the pretty splash screen, and the quiet option suppresses a bunch of text console output.

Comment: @guntbert, good point ;)

Comment: I removed the $vt_handoff, quiet and splash, then add single. But the situation didn't change. What do I miss?


BTW, when I just removed the $vt_handoff, quiet and splash, it displayed "Booting a command list" message and no message but login prompt displayed.

Comment: @matsuzaki, when you do log in, run `tty` and what does it say?  I'm not sure how your virtualization is set up, but it could be that the console is a special virtual device and you'd need to pass "console=/dev/whatever" to redirect the standard linux console there.

Comment: when i logged in and ran "tty", it said "/dev/ttyS0". How do I tell "console=/dev/ttyS0" to kvm when I start the vm?

Comment: @matsuzaki, if you are having the vm bootstrap itself with grub, you need to add that to the kernel command line in your grub config.

Comment: Thank you 4 your advice. I added "console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 single" to the kernel command line, then I can see single user mode prompt.