# PCSX2 not working after kernel upgrade

Tags: upgrade, kernel, pcsx2

I was using a 4.15.0-20-generic default kernel, but for some hardware support with virtualization I was needed to build a new kernel from the kernel.org sources. I've just setted some modules to be loaded as module and not built-in, for details about what I've done its [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198528/blacklist-xhci-hcd)

I use PCSX2 on this computer (the host in my case) but it didn't works with this new kernel (5.4.6), and I get this error :

```
Failed to create the opengl context. Check your drivers support openGL 3.3
```

I already tried to install pcsx2-unstable to see if it makes difference but not and also with another kernel (4.19.91) but I get the same issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found the problem : It's the Nvidia driver which I installed from the Graphic Driver's PPA, but it doesn't install the 32-bit libraries, so I install it with the .run from the Nvidia website which ask me for install the 32-bit libraries. Now it works perfectly.