# Accidentally deleted my /etc/init.d folder from system

Tags: 14.04, init.d

I know this is really bad, but I have accidentally deleted the `init.d` folder from my system. I am using VMWare player to load Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Now my system is not starting properly. I don't have CD to boot from.

Can anyone tell me how to get this folder back by any means?

Answer (score 3):

[Boot into single user mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub), set up networking (use `dhclient`, or `ip` commands, depending on whether you use DHCP or static addresses) and run this command:

```
dpkg -S /etc/init.d
```

It will list all the packages which own files in that directory. Reinstall them all using `apt-get install --reinstall` either manually copying the names, or using this command:

```
dpkg -S /etc/init.d | sed -e 's/,//g' -e 's;: /etc/init.d$;;' | xargs apt-get install --reinstall
```

Comment: reinstall failed to recreate postfix's init script for me....