# unhandled error message within file manager,

Tags: 14.04

my documents, music and video folders have been moved to a tab called bookmarks within file manager and cannot be found when I try to access them also the folders in the picture have decided to take up residence on my desktop and I have no idea why, can this be fixed and if so can you please provide instructions, thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: They have not been moved to that tab, but it seems like something bad happened to them. Try to `fsck` your filesystem and may be you will find your documents in the `lost+found` directory.

Comment: This link may explain how does `fsck` work: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-recover-from-file-system-corruption-using-fsck-and-a-recovery-iso

Comment: thanks @Danatela to be honest the instructions on your link are beyond my comfort zone.

Comment: just wanted to add, i found a kind of a work around without over complicating things, i simply created a new user (as other user accounts on my system seemed unaffected) and deleted the account pictured above.

Comment: Congrats! The question should be closed now. And you should expand your comfort zone if you are planning to continue learning Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps should fix the problem:

1. Create user dirs inside your home directory (issue <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to launch Terminal)

   ```
   mkdir Documents Music Videos Desktop
   ```

   (normally, there should be also Pictures and Downloads dir, but they exist in your home, so I omitted them)
2. Boot into [single user mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub) and try to fix the errors if any exist.

   - choose `fsck` from recovery menu. From it's output, remember the disk node which will be `/dev/sdXY`. `X` is letter, and `Y` is partition number. For example, most systems have `/dev/sda1` though your home partition may be placed on another.
   - choose `root`. It will give you the root shell prompt.
   - type `fsck -p /dev/sdXY`. `sdXY` should be replaced with your remembered disk node. This will automatically repair all fixable errors. Found files will be placed inside the `lost+found` directory.
3. Once you have finished, resume normal boot (hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)
4. Update your user dirs

   ```
   xdg-user-dirs-update
   ```
5. Distribute found files into corresponding directories.