# Installing as guest user so I can't do anything

Tags: networking

I've installed Ubuntu. The installation appears to have worked, but the user details that I put in during installation do not appear. There is only a guest user account available which does not allow me to do anything - I can't create a new 'normal' user account, access my Wifi network or anything. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should log into your ubuntu box in single user mode, which will dump you into a root shell. Then you should be able to create a new user, or to change its password, so you can reboot and log in.

See here on how to do it: [How do I boot into single-user mode from GRUB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub)

To change password for another user, type: `passwd <username>`

To add a new user, use `adduser`.

Comment: By the way: if you chose to encrypt your user's home folder, then changing his password via passwd is not advisable.