# Ubuntu opens with guest log in i cannot switch to user log on

Tags: login

I did receive a previous possible solution using a Terminal command but
since i was logged in as a guest the program was not authorized.

Comment: Do you know the password for the admin account?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try:  Ctrl-Alt-F5 to open a new terminal session, it will require that you login.

Try to run your commands there.

Failing this, You'll need to boot into single-user mode and complete the terminal commands there:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub

Bear in mind that this will log you in as the root user, which is normally disabled, and the root user is extremely powerful.

Once your changes have been made, run the command "reboot" and all will start up normally.

I hope this helps!

Kind Regards