# Xen VM - Ubuntu fails to boot, how can I enter recovery mode?

Tags: boot, xen

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 VM that failed. It could not red/write, so I rebooted.

It now loads as far as this:

```
------
* Starting userspace bootsplash                                         [ OK ]
Checking disk drives for errors. This may take several minutes.
keys:Press C to cancel all checks in progress

keys:
Errors were found while checking the disk drive for /.
keys:Press F to attempt to fix the errors, I to ignore, S to skip mounting, or M for manual recovery
 * Stopping userspace bootsplash                                         [ OK ]
 * Starting Send an event to indicate plymouth is up                     [ OK ]
 * Stopping Send an event to indicate plymouth is up                     [ OK ]
```

---

It then hangs.

The system boots to fast to see grub or much of the boot process. It goes straight past:

```
Press F to attempt to fix the errors, I to ignore, S to skip mounting, or M for manual recover
```

So I do not get chance to press a key.

How can I recover this system?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I boot into single-user mode from GRUB?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub)

Answer (score 0):

There's already a great answer written for this question and you can [find it here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/132983/345941)