# Single User Mode [Snappy Ubuntu Core]

Tags: boot, grub2, ubuntu-core, single-user

I am trying to boot an Intel Nuc running Snappy Ubuntu Core into single user mode. I have tried the [usual method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub), but have gotten no where. Any suggestions for getting this to work would be greatly appreciated.

-Austin

Answer (score 0):

In case you're still able to boot in multi-user mode (which is the default and corresponds to **runlevel 6**), do a regular boot, then start a shell terminal window and run:

```
sudo telinit 1
```

...in order to switch to **runlevel 1** (single user mode).

If you're unable to boot at all, you can use the method explained at https://askubuntu.com/a/132983/389062, but instead of holding the <kbd>shift</kbd> key you hold the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to enter the GRUB menu, then press <kbd>e</kbd> to enter the GRUB editor, look for the first instance of `splash $vt_handoff` and change it to `splash $vt_handoff 1`, then press <kbd>F10</kbd> (or hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while you press <kbd>X</kbd>) in order to boot in single user mode (**runlevel 1**).

After you're finished doing whatever you wanted to do in single user mode, just run:

```
telinit 6
```

...in order to switch back to runlevel 6.