# Ubuntu 18.04 Login Loop

Tags: login-screen

I recently did a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04. I did this because I was having trouble with my computer not booting on 16.04. At first when I upgraded everything worked fine and booted normally. But recently I haven't been able to login, when I enter my password/ username is just goes in a loop and asks me for the password again. I am using a Dell XPS 13 and doing CTRL+ALT+F1 or any other function key during the login screen doesn't work. So if someone could provide some insight into this, that would be great :).

Comment: Did you solve this, happens to me also.

Comment: I just ended up doing another clean install, and it's been working ever since. I didn't have anything in there to lose anyways.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by removing a bad path from my .bashrc. This problem can be produced by a .bashrc/.bash_profile file that cannot be interpreted correctly.

Comment: Explain why this would cause problem described in Q. Explain how to edit files when cannot log in.

Comment: The .bashrc file (usually located in the user's home directory) is loaded when a session is started. If there is a syntax error or bad path in the file, the session might not start properly. To check and edit a .bashrc file without being logged in as a user, you can boot into recovery mode and edit the file from the `root` terminal. For specific instructions, see answers to this related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/842085/accidentally-modified-bashrc-and-now-i-cant-login-despite-entering-password-cor

Comment: @acuriousloop, append correction to the main post text, please )