# Login screen loop in 18.04

Tags: 18.04

Could not get a login screen at first after upgrading from 16.04.
Changed to lightdm and now have a login screen but it seems to be in a loop. 
I get a flash of the desktop and then it returns to the login screen This is the same whether I use Ubuntu or Wayland or Unity environment

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 18.04 Login Loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032090/ubuntu-18-04-login-loop)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and type this command:

```
chown $USER:$USER .Xauthority
```

Comment: Nothing changed after doing this. I still have the same problem.

Comment: Thank you, but nothing changed. I am still stuck in the login loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another machine try to connect via SSH
`ssh your_problematic_box_ip`
Then run `tail -f /var/log/syslog` in that terminal to see what is going on as you try to login.
In my case I have run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` and in that screen have chosen `lightgdm` as my server and then rebooted. I was able to log in normally after that reboot.