# No keyboard or pointer action after upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, mouse

When I upgraded from 16.04 to 16.10 I lost all input from my usb keyboard and mouse when reaching the login screen.

I am not computer literate but have used 16.04 on another laptop without problems. I now cannot access any files on my system.

What should I do?

Comment: While you are at the login screen, do any of the CTRL+ALT+F# keys work (F1 ? If you can get into the console attempt to run the following sudo commands: sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade

Comment: If the OP has not input from the keyboard, I fear CTRL+ALT+F# will give any result.  I suspect a hardware problem (keyboard not connected?)

Comment: Do you get similar results if you  boot in [single user mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub)

Comment: I have no problem with my mouse or keyboard,