# How to become root when your user is hardened?

Tags: permissions, root

I currently have a VM where the user is locked down and i am unable to find any flags. I have tried to use sudo but the account is not a sudoer. I have tried "nano /etc/sudoers" but i received a permission denied message. Any other ideas on how to become root?

Also, this is for a class. Its a basic CTF, and he completely locked down his VM it seems...

Comment: Talk to the owner of the VM

Comment: @dsstorefile i typed that in the root shell, and it just gave me a blank line

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to reboot the Virtual Machine you can boot into single user mode and have root level access assuming the boot loader isn't locked down. If the boot loader is protected then you can try rescuing the machine by booting into ISO mounting the Virtual Machine and editing the configuration, then add your self to the sudoers permissions.

**IF you don't own the Virtual Machine then tread carefully as you may be breaking some laws by try to gain an unauthorised level of access into the system.**

Comment: I have dropped into a root shell. Also, this is a CTF VM. The other guy has mine and i have his. Its for a class, so as long as i gain access to the flags then im good

Comment: Okay I just wanted to cover myself as someone will probably complain otherwise. do you actually have the VM files or something like an SSH session in to it?

Comment: That okay. And yeah, i have the file downloaded onto my own computer and using it in virtual box

Comment: Okay then that make it a lot easier to gain access to root user access if you have the files. First thing is to try this [booting into single user mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub) if the boot loader is protected then boot the VM into an ubuntu ISO and jump across to be able to view the file system.