# Stuck in XScreenSaver

Tags: dual-boot

I have crouton with Ubuntu installed on my Chromebook and I left it idle for about 30 mins. When I got back it was on XScreenSaver and I cannot get out of it. I’ve tried turning off the computer but it doesn’t work.

Comment: What about the other terminals, are the inaccessible too? You can switch between different TTYs by using CTRL+ALT+Fn keys. For example to switch to tty1, we type CTRL+ALT+F1. This way you can at least login and use kill on the console to kill the screensaver process.

Comment: Tried that, all it say is “authentication via PAM cancelled

Comment: Ouch, try to boot into single mode. Here are some tips, how to do that. https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub

Comment: I think if you don’t know the password you have to let your computer run out of battery. I have the same problem