# /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 33, should be 0

Tags: permissions, sudo, pkexec

when I try to use sudo -I command, I get this error:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 33, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

so I tried to use `pkexec chown -R root:root /etc/sudoers` and I get this error:

```
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.
```

Does anyone know what to do with this?

**EDIT:**

I think it is because I ran `sudo chown www-data:www-data /` by a mistake, but I stopped it after few seconds.

What do you think, I should do with that?

Comment: I’d try to fix it by using the [recovery root shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell).

Comment: If you ran `chown -R /`, you might [need to reinstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc).

Answer (score 0):

- [Boot into single user mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub) to gain the root privilege
- Run `chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo`
- Reboot