# I messed up bad. (chmod 700 /bin)

Tags: boot, grub2, permissions

That's not where my problem ends unfortunately, I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and Ive never been able to boot into the grub menu. This means that I have no way to access recovery mode. All I can access is that weird gnu grub command line and a command line login screen that boots me out the moment I log in.
If anybody has any suggestions please sling them my way.

Comment: Unfortunately not, my main issue is not actually having access to a command line interface. @muru

Comment: @yurprivy the first answer on that link suggests using a 'live' system to login, your last comment doesn't make sense given you'd be doing it on a 'live' system unless you're having problems with the 'live' media (which would be a new question).  Restoration of from backup is where I'd go, or script to copy file permissions from your backup being operated from *live* media is likely what I'd do; a variation of what appears in muru's link

Comment: Can't create a live USB, I have no physical access to any other computers. Plus the library has been shut since covid was a thing.

Comment: You're on another device currently, even phones will download ISO media (though I don't know how they'd write to a thumb-drive having never tried), but I know I can order Ubuntu install media from my Ubuntu LoCo very cheaply (https://loco.ubuntu.com/) let alone knowing they are available from other places (ebay etc though more expensive) though I'd opt for one from my Loco myself as I'd have a higher trust level & save money.  Could you login via runlevel 1/recovery? if not implement your backup restoration strategy (or be patient)

Comment: If you can access "the weird grub command line", you can access the grub menu. Then use https://askubuntu.com/a/760064/158442

Comment: That works, thank you!