# Grub broken and password lost

Tags: grub2, password, 21.04

My grub is broken and my PC is booting into the grub command line. I managed to get the PC to reboot with the following commands:

```
set prefix=(hd0,2)
set root=(hd0)
insmod linux
insmod normal
normal
```

My PC reboots normally after I issue the command, however when I reboot my PC returns to the grub command line.

Where is my issue. I cannot fix grub from the bash command line because I lost my password. How do I fix grub and recover my lost password from this point?

[image: Bash prompt]

Comment: Without seeing the grub errors that *dropped* you to the prompt we can't help you.  Are you able to take a picture of the screen with your phone or a camera when you are at the GRUB prompt so we can see the items before it that triggered that drop to the prompt?

Comment: Hi @ThomasWard. I updated the post with the prompt image. No errors are given.

Answer (score 1):

I would put this as a comment but don't have the reputation to do so, so I'll leave an answer instead. If you are able to edit GRUB entries, you could always try entering into [single-user mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub) upon booting up. This will put you inside of a root shell where you can run `passwd <your user name>` and change your password to something new without needing to remember your old one.

Comment: I have managed to boot into single-user-mode and succesfully reset my password. However dispite running sudo update-grub, my grub menu remains broken. Every time I reboot I end up at the grub prompt. How do I restore my grub menu?

Comment: What did you do right before this started happening? Did you update `fstab`, add a drive, change something in `/etc/grub.d/`? Don't hold back information if you want help.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I lost my password and tried to reset it using the bash shell from the grub menu. I must have made changed to grub that now makes it boot to the grub shell every time. Exactly what changes I made I can unfortunately not recall.

Comment: I a computer repeatedly boots into the grub prompt, there must be a procedure to restore grub to it's original state.

Comment: [This](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/) is another tool that I have used when my GRUB appears to be broken. Even though it looks old, I have seen it work for older systems, maybe you could give it a try?