# ubuntu login failure after uninstalling protonvpn

Tags: 20.04, login, data-recovery, recovery-mode

Hi:  After trying for hours to login to protonvpn using its app on ubuntu 20.04 (and not having internet access during that time) I decided to uninstall the protonvpn app, and start over. Big mistake.

I followed these instructions for uninstalling:

https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-ubuntu-vpn-setup/

> "1. Uninstall the official app. To uninstall the official app:

> sudo apt-get autoremove protonvpn
> Remove any leftover files:

> rm -rf ~/.cache/protonvpn

> And

> rm -rf ~/.config/protonvpn"

Neither of the rm (remove) commands appeared to work: both received error messages -- the second of which was "permission denied."

So I added "sudo" before each command. After adding "sudo" to each rm command, there was no response to either command (just a new prompt), so they appeared to work.

However, afterward, I could no longer login to ubuntu. My ubuntu password was not recognized.  (I think what I experienced was a "login loop" as described by others.  When I entered my password after booting, the screen flashed, then returned to the login screen.  I logged in again, same result.)

[My computer is a Lenovo T410, with Intel graphics.  Not nVidia.]

I then tried to use recovery mode for two versions of ubuntu:

Linux 5.11.0-40-generic (recovery mode), and

Linux 5.11.0-38-generic (recovery mode)

Neither recovery worked. Both booted to brand new installs of ubuntu 20. While my ubuntu password now worked, when ubuntu opened, all my files were gone, and all my installed software was gone.  (The screen read "Connect your online accounts," like a fresh install.  There were no files.)

What happened? I was just trying to remove the protonvpn app which was preventing me from getting internet access. Instead, I ruined my whole installation and lost all my data.

I followed the protonvpn uninstall instructions, and lost everything.  (Protonvpn support has not been helpful -- the representative said I must have "mistyped" the uninstall commands.  I didn't.)

I would appreciate suggestions for recovering my ubuntu installation -- or just recovering my lost data.  (How does uninstalling one app cause so much heartache?)

I hope I can get my data back.  It must still be on my hard drive.

Thank you.

Comment: Before trying anything to fix it, I’d log in to a live usb session to try to find your files and back them up. Then you can try to fix it without jeopardising the chances of recovering your lost data.

Comment: I suspect you mistyped the `sudo rm` commands and deleted system packages. You should not have been asked for permission to delete files from your home directory. I would suggest examining the output of `history`...but you can't log in.

Comment: Will:  If I login with a live USB, will I be able to access the hard drive?  ( I thought a live USB session would only be able to access the USB.)  If I can access the hard drive, would the file names be visible?  Could I copy the Documents folder and paste it to another USB (or SD)?

Comment: Will:  I logged in to a live USB session.  There are no files -- I cannot see the hard drive.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Well there is nothing obviously going to cause chaos, in the commands you ran.  My guess is something in an autostartup script, is expecting to call something that isn't there, and so its failing.

You should be able to fix that, by either finding the problem, or simply clearing out (and replacing) the skel files.  Either of which can be done easily if you can get sudo access to the files.

That can normally be done, several ways.  The easiest is to login at the console.  This can normally be done, remotely, if you have ssh-server running, or depending on your login gui, you may be able to tell it to go to a text console.  You may be able to login as root, if you set it to allow that.

Failing that, you should be able to go single user mode (see [How do I boot into single-user mode from GRUB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub))

The intention of recovery mode, is that it is a completely fresh OS, from which you can mount your original file system, and edit the files directly.

You ideally, need to find out what is failing and fix it.  I'd start by grepping everything in your home directory for protonvpn.  If in doubt, though, you may want to create a new user from the console, and login as them, which presumably won't have the same problem.  Then if needs be you can go back to console and see the difference between the skel files the new user got created, and the ones your old user had.

Ideally, someone with direct protonvpn experience can help you, but I hope I've helped by outlining what I'd do.

Comment: [first half.  Adding a responsive comment is not easy.]

sibaz:  Thanks so much for your suggestions.  While I have used ubuntu for several years, I am unfamiliar with almost everything (really everything) you suggested I try.

Any chance you could walk me thru this?

I am not familiar with skel files.

I don't know what "login at the console" means.  Nor what a "text console" is.

I don't know if I can login as root.  (I thought I was always root, but I guess not.)

Are those things you would suggest I try first?  (Were your suggestions in descending order?)

Comment: [second half of response.]

I don't know what single user mode is.  The link you provided will probably tell me how. But I was wondering if I should try the other steps first? 

I don't know what grepping my home directory means.

I don't know how to create a new user from console.  Does that mean a text console?

To compare skel files created by my old user self, and my new user self, what should I be looking for.  

Sorry, I'm a noob at this.  Hoping you might help me out.

Comment: ok, so from what you've said, I can't tell if you're using KDE, Gnome or some other login manager.  So I can't tell you how to find out or if you can select a different login manager.  I used to use Gnome, and seem to remember a drop down list, which allowed a console login.  I currently use KDE which doesn't allow that.

Comment: Failing a straight login, if you have another computer, and can find the IP address of the computer that you're trying to login to, either run xterm, or konsole (if it's linux) or install putty if its not, and try to ssh to the IP of the computer you want to login to, as your original username and password.  If you succeed you have a console login

Comment: Alternatively, reboot the computer and start pressing F12 repeatedly until you get the grub menu.  When you do, follow the link I gave to add 'single' as a boot option, that will cause it to boot to single user mode, which is a console.  It normally prompts for the root password to let you login for this

Comment: If you manage to get access to your home directory, check /etc/skel which contains the skeleton files for a new profile.  If you have to, backup and replace each of the files in your home directory, with the copy in /etc/skel, to reset the basic config files

Comment: If none of those work, get a bootable DVD (or USB stick as mentioned above), like the Ubuntu Server LTS DVD, and reboot the machine to the liveCD.  Then get a console, cat /proc/partitions to find which partition your old OS was on, mount it using the 'sudo mount /dev/sd? /mnt' command to mount that on /mnt, then you should be able find your old home directory on /mnt/home/<username>

Comment: Hi again sibaz!   I don't know what a login manager is or does.  I'm using straight Ubuntu 20.04.  If it includes a login manager, then that's what I guess I'm using.

Comment: I do have another computer (which is how I posted here).  I will try to get a console login.  (Have not previously used xterm, konsole, or putty, so will try one or more.)  If I'm understanding, if I can get a console login to work, I will essentially have access to the bad laptop OS/data from the good laptop OS, and can copy my data files from the bad laptop to the good laptop.  Is that right?

Comment: Well, single user mode did not work for me.  I tried twice (inserted the word "single" as described in the link).  Both times it booted eventually to a login screen, and both times the "login loop" happened:  the screen flashed, my ubuntu password was not recognized, and I got another login screen.  (By the way, the first time I inserted "single" there were only about 14 lines of code.  The second time, there were 2+ pages of code.)

Comment: Re: "reboot the machine to the liveCD. Then get a console"  -- I'm booted to a live USB of ubuntu 20.04.   (You suggested the ubuntu Server version.  Does that make a difference?)       Re:  "get a console" -- how?

Comment: When you turn on a linux computer, you either see a splash screen (aka quiet mode) or the console showing you the boot log.  When its finished booting, it'll either present you with a console login prompt, or it'll start up a graphical environment, and start a login manager, which will prompt you to login (and ask you for a username/password)

Comment: yes, if you can access a remote console, you can copy files to/fro but more importantly you can reconfigure the target computer and fix your login.

Comment: a single user login, will prompt for a password, but it expects a root login.  If you didn't set a password for root (and by default it won't set one), then that avenue is closed.

Comment: Hi sibaz:  Can you point me to link that would explain what I would do in console mode, once I get there?  Regarding "fix your login" -- I don't know how I would go about doing that.  It sounds like I should be able to get to a console from a live USB session, but I'm not finding (1) how to get a console, nor (2) what I would do once I get a console.  Also, is there an advantage in a live USB console, versus a remote console?  I'm reading posts here about console mode, but they seem to be aimed at more advanced users.  Am trying to find a primer on console -- what is it, and how its used.

Comment: Hi Sue, that is difficult, because it really depends on whats causing the problem.  You will probably want to check the logs, and see what you can find.  The logs live in /var/logs you can look at the end of each file with tail <file> Find instructions on tail with man tail, but really you should buy a good book on using linux shell/console/bash.

Comment: That said, if you can get a remote console running, you can configure that console to use the actual screen and try to run up X, that might tell you whats wrong too.  So try export DISPLAY=:0.0 then run startx or just X.  As long as you're connected remotely, you'll be able to watch the log thats output to the console to see whats not working (assuming that's where the problem is)

Comment: If you can start a gui, you should be able to use the settings tools in there to create a second user, which might be something you can use, if your main user is broken.  Otherwise you might just as well reinstall your machine.  If you do that without reformatting the disks, you'll still have access to all your old files, as the installer will just wipe the actual binarys and configs, not your data.

Comment: Hi sibaz:  Really, I could reinstall ubuntu 20.04, and my data would still be there?  Are you sure?   I assume the applications would need to be reinstalled in any case, but if the data they use would still be accessible on the harddrive, that would get me going forward again.

Comment: Would my file/folder structure still be in place -- would the data be in the same folders?

Comment: when you install ubuntu, the default option is to reformat and restructure all the disks.  If you skil that and go manual, you can select the existing disks, and tell it not to reformat them, just to reinstall.  That way it'll recreate all the configs for a standard install, anything not part of that will be left alone, and clearly all your data will be left alone.  All you'll have to do is re-setup all the applications you use.